# How to read file or folder in subfolder from Android filesystem

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create a File object by pointing it to a file or folder in another folder on the internal sdcard of an Android device.
For some reason, the exists() method keeps returning false whenever I'm trying to point it to any file or folder which is a subfile/folder of another folder.

See the following example:

```
File fileObject = new File("/mnt/sdcard/folder/file.txt");
```

In this case fileObject.exists() returns false even though I have the following folder structure:

```
sdcard
- folder
  - subfolder
  - file.txt
```

Whenever I try to call

```
fileObject.exists();
```

it returns false at all times. When I try to read the folder "folder" this method call will return true.
This method call will also be false in the following case:

```
File fileObject = new File("/mnt/sdcard/folder/subfolder/");
```

It looks like whenever I try to read a file or a folder which is in a higher level than the root of the folder structure the exists() method call will return false.

I read somewhere that my application might not be allowed to read all the data on the internal sdcard so I also tried this with the following folder:

```
getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
```

When trying to read files or folders in a subfolder of this folder it also returns false.

Does anyone know what causes this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Kevin.

Comment: `even though I have the following folder structure:`. Well you see that it does not start with `mnt` there.

Comment: You have asked for the read external storage permission in your manifest file?

Comment: `getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`. Please tell which path that is exactly. Wich folders and files did you put/create in that location and how?

Comment: @greenapps As far as I know mnt is always there. It's like the root of the internal and external sdcard so that shouldn't be a problem.
I am not asking for permission to use the external storage since I am reading files from the internal sdcard.
The getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() returns the following path as far as I remember: /data/data/package_name/files or something like that.

Comment: 'I am not asking for permission to use the external storage since I am reading files from the internal sdcard.'. The internal 'sdcard' is considered EXTERNAL memory/storage.

Comment: 'As far as I know mnt is always there.'. Why are you mentioning that? Your first path or folder structure starts with mnt. Your second path not. That's what i said.

Comment: @greenapps /mnt is always the root folder for the files on the internal sdcard, that's what I meant. The other one starts with /data because it's in another folder and not a subfolder of /mnt.

If you are right about that external thing, that is probably the cause of my problem. I'll try it, even though I would suspect some type of error in my logcat instead of File.exists() returning false.
If you would create an answer with that suggestion I will accept it if it works.

Comment: It appears you were right. After adding the permission you were talking about I was able to read the file just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask for the read external storage permission in your manifest file.